# ApexCharts: Grouped stacked bar charts subcategories naming

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bar-chart, apexcharts, stacked-bar-chart

I would like to have the sub category label name as like below and could not get the answer. Can anyone please guide.

What can enable the Sub Category details in the chart

```js
var options = {
    series: json,
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 350,
        stacked: true,
    },
    stroke: {
       width: 1,
       colors: ['#fff']
    },
    dataLabels: {
        formatter: (val) => {
            return val  
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: [
            'JAN',                   
            'FEB',                                       
            'MAR',                   
            'APR',                   
            'MAY'
                    
        ],
              
        labels: {
            formatter: (val) => {
                return val
            }
        }
    },
    fill: {
        opacity: 1,
    },
    colors: ['#0097df', '#0097df', '#8fce00', '#8fce00', '#FF0000', '#FF0000', '#FFA500','#FFA500'],
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
        horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmgB6.png)

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the sample data.